# chart.js irregular time series produces incorrect tooltip

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chart.js and have a chart with 2 line series and 2 bar series. The series can have irregular times, aka, there may be a missing interval or two in a series.

As far as plotting, it actually looks fine. But the tooltip will display the data for the next point that is populated, even if its missing for that period.

In other words, 3 of the series have a point for Jan, but the fourth series' first point is for February. It'll show the first 3 correct for January, and the fourth point on the January tooltip will be for February. Then on February, it'll show all four series February data correctly. I would expect the Jan tooltip to only show the 3 series that it has data for.

```
 tooltips: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false
}
```

I am working on a fiddle, but unfortunately I'm having trouble getting that to work (like, display at all). I will update the question once its working.

I've also tried mode being x, and label.

Here is the fiddle. Hover over the first data point and you will see the values for the two "you" series:
https://jsfiddle.net/kqofb5m2/3/

Comment: Since you set `mode:'index'`, the `tooptips` fetch data according to `index`, not the x-axis. This cause the tooltips find the position of you cursor,then mapping it to the index of data.

Comment: I've tried both index and x. Both do not function as desired.